# Java code help. Error within code

Tags: java

Attached is some java code I am practicing for fun. I am very new to this and it may seem small to most but I could use a little help about where I went wrong with this. Any input for feedback would be appreciated.`

```
package javaapplication28;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
/**
*
* @author dustin
*/
public class JavaApplication28 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);



    System.out.println("How many games of Black Jack do you want to play? ");
    int g = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("How much would you like to bet per hand? ");
    int bet = scanner.nextInt();

    Random rand = new Random();



    int player = 0;
    int dealer = 0;
    int won = bet * 2;
    int blackjack = 0;      

    String games = Integer.toString(g);





            switch(games)
            {
            case "1":

                    for (int i = 0; i < g; i++) 
                    {   
                     blackjack = rand.nextInt((21 - 1) + 1);
                     System.out.print(blackjack);
                     dealer += player;
                    }
                     System.out.println("");
                     System.out.println("Dealer wins");
                     break;

            case "2":
                    for (int i = 0; i < g; i++) 
                    {   
                     blackjack = rand.nextInt((21 - 1) + 1);
                     System.out.print(blackjack);
                     dealer -= player;
                    }
                     System.out.println("");
                     System.out.println("Player wins");
                     break;

                     if (dealer >= player){

                        System.out.println("Dealer wins!" +blackjack+ ".");
                     }
                        break;

                    else (dealer <= player)
                            {
                        System.out.println("Player wins" +won+ " dollars!");
                            }
                            break;




            }``
}

}
```

Comment: Use a debugger.... oh and actually spend time formatting your code if you expect others to take time and help you.

Comment: I did use a debugger, and it tells me the if and else statement at the bottom of the code is an "unreachable statement".

Comment: well if you fixed your formatting then it would be easier to read your code. Also, putting logic inside case statements makes things hard to read as well. Most people, including myself, aren't going to take the time to try and piece together your code visually.

Comment: Spend time formatting your code, and **typing up the details of your problem**. Don't expect people to fix your formatting, run your code, intuit the expected behaviour, and find the place(s) where the actual behaviour deviates from it.

Comment: @D.White It's unreachable because you put a `break;` before.

Comment: Well redFIVE thanks for the bashing. Feel more like you telling me everything im doing wrong rather then telling me to add "logic" which I have no idea what you mean by that. If you mean "comments" alright, point taken. I'm sure I said I have very  minimal if no experience so please do not except me to know you 5+ years of experience lingo. I also did not understand what you mean by fixing my format. Sorry bud.

Answer (score 0):

Case "2" contains a break before the if statement, which will make it unreachable.

Having one break at the end of your case will make the if statement run.

```
case "2":
    for (int i = 0; i < g; i++) 
    {   
        blackjack = rand.nextInt((21 - 1) + 1);
        System.out.print(blackjack);
        dealer -= player;
    }

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Player wins");

    if (dealer >= player) {
        System.out.println("Dealer wins!" +blackjack+ ".");
    } else (dealer <= player) {
        System.out.println("Player wins" +won+ " dollars!");
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: I have not looked at any other problems. Just addressing your issue regarding "the if and else statement at the bottom of the code is an 'unreachable statement'". Please make sure to include any errors from the debugger in your questions.

Comment: Thank you sir, That was exactly it. I also found out i need to add comments within my code so people can understand it sooner rather then reading ALL of it. I will also reply with what the debugger has responding with. Thank you.

Comment: Indenting is also very helpful when reading code. This can be handled quite well by most IDE's.

Comment: What do you mean by indenting?

Comment: The starting position of text on a line. The code inside an if statement for example should be indented so it can be easily seen where it starts and ends.